# Grails GORMS find all where collection property is not empty

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i am fighting with gorms a bit:

```
String data = new JSON(Object.executeQuery("from Product p where p.subis not empty"))
```

is working just fine

however:

```
String data = new JSON(Product.findAllBySubIsNotEmpty())
```

does not work. the error

```
No signature of method: com.path.Object.findAllBySubIsNotEmpty() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

for the purpose of clean code i would prefer gorms syntax to hql queries, any ideas why this wont work?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `findAllBySubIsNotNull`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It seems](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) that you can't query for objects which has not-empty collection with dynamic finders (`findAllBy*`). You can do it using [`withCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html) instead:

```
Product.withCriteria {
    isNotEmpty("sub")
}
```

It uses Hibernate's Criteria API, which is a bit more powerful than dynamic finders. [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) is quite comprehensive about it.

Answer (score 1):

The following [`findAllBy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) query should work:

```
Product.findAllBySubIsNotNull()
```

You could also use a [where query](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries):

```
Product.where { sub.isEmpty() == false }
```

Comment: isnotnull will throw the same error as isnotempty sadly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use where query like this

```
Product.where {
   sub.size() > 0
}
```

'==' in where queries equivalent to sizeGt criteria